# iOS app crash on -[_UIViewAdditiveAnimationAction runActionForKey:object:arguments:]

Tags: ios, uikit

iOS app crash on

```
-[_UIViewAdditiveAnimationAction runActionForKey:object:arguments:]
```

This is crash log is from Apple.

I am getting crash log as below:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  UIKit                          0x0000000187fbb4d8 -[_UIViewAdditiveAnimationAction runActionForKey:object:arguments:] + 776
1  UIKit                          0x0000000187fbb4c8 -[_UIViewAdditiveAnimationAction runActionForKey:object:arguments:] + 760
2  QuartzCore                     0x00000001874c0014 CA::Layer::set_bounds(CA::Rect const&, bool) + 404
3  QuartzCore                     0x00000001874bfde8 -[CALayer setBounds:] + 100
4  UIKit                          0x0000000187e61438 -[_UISwitchInternalViewNeueStyle1 _transitionKnobToPressed:on:animated:] + 1104
5  UIKit                          0x000000018815cff0 -[_UISwitchInternalViewNeueStyle1 setOnTintColor:] + 104
6  UIKit                          0x000000018815e800 -[UISwitch initWithCoder:] + 292
7  UIKit                          0x0000000188287bd4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 672
8  UIKit                          0x000000018828791c -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 336
9  UIKit                          0x000000018817290c -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 136
10 UIKit                          0x00000001881730e0 -[UIRuntimeEventConnection initWithCoder:] + 68
11 UIKit                          0x0000000188287bd4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 672
12 UIKit                          0x0000000188287d4c UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1048
13 UIKit                          0x000000018828791c -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 336
14 UIKit                          0x0000000188171c74 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1220
15 UIKit                          0x000000018802ace0 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 376
16 UIKit                          0x0000000187dffe8c -[UIViewController loadView] + 176
17 UIKit                          0x0000000187cc723c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 144
18 UIKit                          0x0000000187d847e8 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 72
19 UIKit                          0x0000000187d846cc -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 404
20 UIKit                          0x0000000187d83920 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 132
21 UIKit                          0x0000000187d834e4 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 868
22 UIKit                          0x0000000187d8310c -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 60
23 UIKit                          0x0000000187d83074 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 208
24 UIKit                          0x0000000187cc2ff0 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 644
25 QuartzCore                     0x00000001874c9f14 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
26 QuartzCore                     0x00000001874c4b20 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
27 QuartzCore                     0x00000001874c49e0 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
28 QuartzCore                     0x00000001874c407c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
29 QuartzCore                     0x00000001874c3dd0 CA::Transaction::commit() + 516
30 UIKit                          0x0000000187cc60c0 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 5800
31 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001827285a4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
32 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182728038 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
33 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182725d38 __CFRunLoopRun + 724
34 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182654dc0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
35 GraphicsServices               0x000000018d7a8088 GSEventRunModal + 180
36 UIKit                          0x0000000187d2ef44 UIApplicationMain + 204
37 Instazz                        0x0000000100151360 main (main.m:19)
38 libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000197aa28b8 start + 4
```

Please help me with this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you show us the code, which caused that error?

Comment: This particular crash is randomly not on particular line.

Comment: Looks like a UISwitch in your nib/storyboard may have some state corruption. Try removing it and adding a new one in its place.